# systemd error with user having a dot (.) in name: Invalid user/group name or numeric ID

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, ubuntu-18.04, systemd

Linux Ubuntu 18. MariaDB 10.3.
MariaDB service fails to start throwing a systemd error. The reason seems to be that the userid contains a dot (.).

`systemd[1]: Invalid user/group name or numeric ID: myuser.withdot`

Configuration:

The service file from MariaDB is /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/migrated.conf, and it contains:

```
[Service]
User=myuser.withdot
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that seems to be working, is replacing the user name with id:

```
id myuser.withdot
uid=12345(myuser.withdot) ...
```

Replace the user name with id in the systemd config file:

```
[Service]
User=m12345
```

Reload the config file:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Restart the service:

```
sudo service mariadb start
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, dot included username is valid which is converted with 'id' command without alphabet character in 'User' value. i.e. numeric uid value, after 'id' command returns.